# Circumscribed circles of squares outside a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

On the edges of triangle $ABC$ we build two squares $ABDE$ and $ACFG$ which $Q$ and $R$ are their center respectively. $P$ is itersection of $BG$ and $EC$.
Also we know that $BG=EC$ and $BG \perp EC$.

Prove:

1. $P$ is intersection of the two circumscribed circles of the two squares.
2. $P$ is on $DF$

Comment: $P$ is on $EF$? $DF$?

Comment: I changed $BG\bot EC$ (coded as BG\bot EC) to $BG\perp EC$ (coded as BG\per EC).  The latter has proper spacing. ${}\quad{}$

Comment: Constructing the exterior square *BCHI*, and doing the same for the other two pairs of sides, we analogously create the points *Q* and *R*. Then *AP*, *BQ*, and *CR* intersect at the [Vecten point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vecten_points).

Comment: @Lucian, but how does it help to solve the problem?

Comment: @BlessYourKarma: I just thought you'd be interested to know that.

Answer (score 0):

HINT :

For the first, note that 
$$\angle{GPC}=\angle{GAC}\quad\text{and}\quad \angle{EPB}=\angle{EAB}.$$

For the second, if you mean that we have to prove that $P$ is on $DF$, note that  $$\angle{APF}=\angle{ACF}\quad\text{and}\quad \angle{APD}=\angle{ABD}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't understand how this will help me solve the problem. can I have another hint? btw yes it's $DF$

Comment: @BlessYourKarma: Do you know the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)? From this theorem, we can see that four points $G,A,C,P$ are on the circle whose diameter is the line segment $GC$. Also, four points $E,A,P,B$ are on the circle whose diameter is the line segment $EB$. For the second, we have the two equalities I wrote from the theorem, so we have $\angle{APF}+\angle{APD}=180^\circ$.